# How to set value in a reactive form control in angular, using the value obtained from the call back function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, bootbox

I am using bootbox here, and is able to recieve the value from prompt, and is able to console it also( using the call-back function). But I am unable to set the same value, in one of the form controls (overallPercent) of addAssessentForm.

*(I want to set value obtained from the prompt input box (on button click) to a reactive form inputbox)*[image: my prompt][image: is able to get value in console]
[image: form field where I want to obtain the same value, prefilled (on right button click, of prompt)]

HTML Code :

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" [attr.disabled]="disabledLocation" formControlName="rural" (click)="onRuralClick($event)" />
  <label class="mx-2"> Rural</label>
</div>
```

TS Code :

```js
onRuralClick(e) {
  let ans;
  let ruralCheck = e.target.checked;
  if (ruralCheck == true) {
    bootbox.prompt({
      title: "Enter Ratio",
      size: 'small',
      centerVertical: true,
      buttons: {
        cancel: {
          label: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>',
          className: 'btn-danger',
        },
        confirm: {
          label: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>',
          className: 'btn-success'
        }

      },
      callback: function(result: number) {
        ans = result;
        console.log(ans);
      },



    });

    // this.addAssessmentForm.controls['overallPercent'].setValue(ans);
  }


}
```

A method, which initializes all form controls:

```js
createForm() {
  this.addAssessmentForm = this.fb.group({
    assessmentId: [],
    assessmentName: [
      ],
    ],
    assessmentDescription: [null, [Validators.maxLength(200)]],
    startDateCheck: [],
    startDate: [],
    endDateCheck: [],
    endDate: [],
    totalNumberOfDay: [this.calnumofDays, [Validators.required]],
    class: [],
    status: [true],
    rural: [],
    urban: [],
    overallPercent: [],
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the arrow function if you want to access class variables:

```js
onRuralClick(e) {
  let ans;
  let ruralCheck = e.target.checked;
  if (ruralCheck == true) {
    bootbox.prompt({
      title: "Enter Ratio",
      size: 'small',
      centerVertical: true,
      buttons: {
        cancel: {
          label: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>',
          className: 'btn-danger',
        },
        confirm: {
          label: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>',
          className: 'btn-success'
        }

      },
      callback: (result: number) => {
        ans = result;
        this.addAssessmentForm.controls['overallPercent'].setValue(ans);
        console.log(ans);
      },



    });

    
  }


}
```